# How to get php Json array data of Jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My jQuery Ajax code:

```
$(".comment").click(function(){

    var id  =  $(this).data("id");
    var name = $("#username_"+id).val();



    if(name==''){
        alert("Please Fill All Fields");
    }else{

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "comments",
        data:{username:name},

        dataType: "JSON",

        success: function(jsonStr){
            $("#cmt_output").html(JSON.stringify(jsonStr));
        }
    });
    }
});
```

My Php Code:
............

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","quotes") or die("Error".mysqli_error($con));

$name   = $_POST['username'];

$user   = get_userdetails();
$vw_id  = $user->id;

$query  = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tlb_comments(user_id,comments) values ('$vw_id','$name')");

$comments = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tlb_comments");
$avatar   = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM tlb_avatar WHERE `vw_id`='".$vw_id."'");




$avatar_select  =  mysqli_fetch_all($avatar);
$comment_select =  mysqli_fetch_all($comments);

array_push($avatar_select,$comment_select);
echo json_encode($avatar_select);
```

Comment: You question is unclear. Please describe what you exactly want and what is happening wrong there

Comment: How I display json array to jquey ajax

Comment: use `$("#cmt_output").html(jsonStr);` . You already used `dataType: "JSON",`. Also it is not clear that how exactly you want to show that json data,and also what json data you get is unkown to us

Comment: Okay.Thanks.Now I will Try that method...............